# Creating an index on a nested field

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

I have a MongoDB document that is structured similar to the structure below follows. There are is a large number of these documents with thousands of people in them, so I want to speed things up by putting indexes on the people.#.search_columns.surname and people.#.search_columns.givenname. Howe can I do this in MongoDB? Thanks for your help.

```
[_id] => MongoId Object (
    [$id] => 53b1b1ab72f4f852140dbdc9
)
[name] => People From 1921
[people] => Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [name] => Barada, Valentine
        [search_columns] => Array (
            [surname] => Array (
                [0] => Mardan,
                [1] => Barada
            )
            [givenname] => Array (
                [0] => Valentine
            )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [name] => Barsaloux, Nicholas
        [search_columns] => Array (
            [surname] => Array (
                [1] => Barsaloux
            )
            [givenname] => Array (
                [0] => Nicholas
            )
            [place] => Array (
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create indexes for nested fields using the dot notation:

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({'people.search_columns.surname': 1});
db.collection.ensureIndex({'people.search_columns.givenname': 1});
```

Comment: Thanks! The examples I was finding did something like people.[0].search_columns.surname, so I wasn't sure how to do it globally like this. Thank you for your help!